Datepicker JQuery, Select 1 Date and Outputs 2 range dates based from selected (how many nights section) in a single Text Field
I am using JQuery Datepicker and I am having trouble on how to implement the situation where I can select Number of Nights, Get the value of # of nights and When you select a Date, Date output should be (Ex: 06/05/24 - 06/06/24).
For Example: I selected 5 nights and selected 06/05/24 from the date-picker. My output should be 06/05/24 - 06/10/24.

Here is my code on selecting date:
HTML:
<p>Pick a Date</p>
<div class="date-picker">
  <div class="div-d-picker">
    <img id="datepicker" src="assets/images/ic_calendar.png" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="picked-date">
    <input type="text" id="popupDatepicker" placeholder="20 Jan - 22 Jan" />
  </div>
</div>

JQuery:
$(function () {
  //Get value of # of nights
  var range = $("#quantity2");

  $("#popupDatepicker").datepicker({
    minDate: 1,
    showButtonPanel: true,
    changeMonth: true,
  });

  //DatePicker appears when clicking the Date Icon Image
  $("#datepicker").click(function (e) {
    var visible = $("#popupDatepicker").datepicker("widget").is(":visible");
    $("#popupDatepicker").datepicker(visible ? "hide" : "show");
  });
});

